# Html CSS table row questions

Tags: html, asp.net, css

I am having trouble adding a row at the very bottom of a table. The table has two columns, when I tried to add a new row with 2 columns, it actually start from the second column and add a new column as the third column. Are there anything to do with css?

```
<div>
    <table width="972" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="page">
        <tr style="height: 11px">
            <td align="left" valign="top" class="column1Top" style="width: 217px; height: 11px;"></td>  
            <td style="height: 11px" align="right" valign="top" class="topSection_1"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="3" align="center" valign="top" class="column1" style="width: 217px"></td>
            <td
        </tr>
            <td valign="top" style="width: 755px; height: 426px;" rowspan="1" align="left"></td>  
   </table>
</div>
```

that's basically what the table looks like, when I tried to add  as the very last line, the first column of that line is actually at the second column of the table and a new column has been added as third line...

Comment: Can you post the HTML markup and what you are trying to do? It's hard for us to tell without the actual code. It seems like an unclosed tag kind of problem.

Answer (score 1):

You might look at the tags that you haven't close properly like in your second `<tr>` or table row.

```
 <tr>
 <td rowspan="3" align="center" valign="top" class="column1" style="width: 217px"></td>
 <td
 </tr>
 <td valign="top" style="width: 755px; height: 426px;" rowspan="1" align="left"></td>
```

If you look at the 2nd `<td>` it does not have a closing tag `</td>` let alone a right angled bracket `>`.

So, just correcting it on the fly, it would probably should look like this:

```
 <tr>
 <td rowspan="3" align="center" valign="top" class="column1" style="width: 217px"></td>
 <td valign="top" style="width: 755px; height: 426px;" rowspan="1" align="left"></td> 
 </tr>
```

You might want to visit [tutorials point](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/html/index.htm) to learn more on HTML.

Comment: don't worry about the closing tag or any syntax errors, I was just typing in a hurry...

Comment: It's good if you post a [jsfiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net) or an image to graphically show what you meant.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div>
        <table width="972" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="page">
            <tr style="height: 11px">
                <td align="left" valign="top" class="column1Top" style="width: 217px; height: 11px;">111</td>
                <td style="height: 11px" align="right" valign="top" class="topSection_1">222</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td rowspan="3" align="center" valign="top" class="column1" style="width: 217px">333</td>
                <td valign="top" style="width: 755px; height: 426px;" rowspan="1" align="left">444</td>
                <td rowspan="3" align="center" valign="top" class="column1" style="width: 217px">333</td>
                <td valign="top" style="width: 755px; height: 426px;" rowspan="1" align="left">444</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
```

Comment: Can you add some short summary of introduced changes so that future readers won't have to compare your code with original one? Also seems that you've adressed the same issue as the other answer written in 2013